# Fundamental group of a space of infinite genus and an accumulation point

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a point removed is $\mathbb{Z}$.
The fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $n$ points removed is the free group of $n$ generators.

1. Is the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{N}$ removed the free group on infinite generators?
2. What about  $\mathbb{R}^2$  with an accumulation point:  $\mathbb{R}^2$  minus ${0} \bigcup$ ${\frac{1}{n}}       $$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Intuitively the fundamental group has to be different for 2. since all loops at ${0}$ wrap around infinitely many holes.

Comment: The answer to (1) is yes, and can be proven using Van Kampen's Theorem.  The answer for (2) is that the resulting fundamental group is not free: the space in question deformation retracts onto the [Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring), which has uncountable fundamental group.

Comment: @Jim Belk: Actually, it is not homotopy equivalent to Hawaiian earring since the origin is still excluded from the space in question. Moreover, as any non compact connected surface it homotopy equivalent to a connected graph with countably many edges and hence has free fundamental group of countable rank.

Comment: @studiosus Good point -- I interpreted the question as having  $0$ not removed, but looking more carefully at the notation in the question, it seems that perhaps the OP intended to remove it.  If $0$ is included in the space, then I ought to be right, but if $0$ is not included, then you are right.

Comment: @Jim Belk: clearly zero is removed from the plane in the question.

Comment: I intended to remove it, but with zero included it still makes a fine question. (very cool fact about the Hawaiian Earring!) @studiosus It seems very weird to me that the fundamental groups for (1) and (2) are isomorphic. Are the spaces homeomorphic aswell?

Comment: Because you've removed the limit point of the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ from the space, there's no way to get a finite lengthed path which loops around infinitely many removed points (which is the case if $0$ were still in the space), and so (because there are obviously no relations among the generators) the fundamental group of the second space is also free on (countably) infinitely many generators.

Comment: @Lee Wang: Both fundamental groups are free but they are not isomorphic. One has finite rank and the other has infinite countable rank.

Comment: @studiousus: Could you possibly justify what you said above: that a noncompact surface is homotopy equivalent to a graph?